# Ruby strange equality check in a loop '-'[0]

Tags: ruby

I really can't understand how the below piece of code is working...

```
options.each { |p|  
  if p[0] == '-'[0]  
    break  
  end...
```

does it really check for this string? "-[0]"?? or am i missing something?
sorry for this dumb question, but my mind is blocked right now...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What `'-'[0]` will give you in Ruby 1.8 or lower is 45, which is the ASCII value for the `-` character. So what this is doing is checking to see if `p[0]` is equal to 45.

In Ruby 1.9, `'-'[0]` will give you `'-'`, so it is recommended to use `String#ord` instead if you want the ASCII value:

```
if p[0] == '-'.ord
```

Answer (score 0):

The comparison looks to be a work around for the different string[index] semantics in ruby between version 1.8 and 1.9. @robbrit described the differing behavior between these two.  Since both the left and right side of the comparison are using [0] to get the first char of the string, they will either both get the ascii ordinal (1.8) or both get the single character length string (1.9) and so have a valid comparison in either version.  Another common construct to work around this behavior variance is to use range subscript to get a single-char string in either version of ruby, eg:

```
str[0..0] == '-'
```